# JPA2 CriteriaQuery empty result

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

This code using JPA2 criteria query return an empty result list:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<VwReplPrevia> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(VwReplPrevia.class);
Root<VwReplPrevia> root = query.from(VwReplPrevia.class);
query.multiselect(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos), 
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroCartaoPostagem),
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoServico),
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.quantidadeItems),
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.valorServico));
TypedQuery<VwReplPrevia> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
String contrato       = StringUtils.trim(paginador.getEntityBean().getContrato());
String centroCustos   = StringUtils.trim(paginador.getEntityBean().getCentroCustos());
String cartaoPostagem = StringUtils.trim(paginador.getEntityBean().getCartaoPostagem());
String servico        = StringUtils.trim(paginador.getEntityBean().getServico());
query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroContrato), contrato));
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(centroCustos)) {
        criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos), "9912231583"));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cartaoPostagem)) {
        criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroCartaoPostagem), cartaoPostagem));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(servico)) {
        criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoServico), servico));
    }

    query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos)));
    query.groupBy(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos), 
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroCartaoPostagem), 
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoServico),
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.quantidadeItems),
            root.get(VwReplPrevia_.valorServico));
List<VwReplPrevia> resultado = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The same query, using native query, return the corret number of results.

```
String sql = "SELECT vwreplprev0_.sdan8  AS col_0_0_, " +
   "vwreplprev0_.sdcnid AS col_1_0_, " +
   "vwreplprev0_.sdlitm AS col_2_0_, " +
   "vwreplprev0_.sduorg AS col_3_0_, " +
   "vwreplprev0_.sdaexp AS col_4_0_ "  +
"FROM   sfe_view.vw_f4211_repl_previa vwreplprev0_ " +
"WHERE  vwreplprev0_.sddmct = '9912231583' " +
"GROUP  BY vwreplprev0_.sdan8, " +
      "vwreplprev0_.sdcnid, " +
      "vwreplprev0_.sdlitm, " +
      "vwreplprev0_.sduorg, " +
      "vwreplprev0_.sdaexp " +
"ORDER  BY vwreplprev0_.sdan8 ASC  ";
    Collection<PreviaFaturaBean> result =    getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
    paginador.setColecaoDeRegistros(result);
```

I have no idea what's the problem. My only reference in implementing via Criteria Query was http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html, someone can give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The following part looks wrong, and not matching with the native query:

```
query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroContrato), contrato));
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(centroCustos)) {
    criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos), "9912231583"));
}
```

It should probably be

```
query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.numeroContrato), "9912231583"));
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(centroCustos)) {
    criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(VwReplPrevia_.codigoCentroCustos), centroCustos));
}
```

If that's not the problem, see which SQL query is generated in the logs by your JPA engine, and compare it with the native query to find what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for the error, but even with the correct version the output is the same.

Comment: And what is the generated SQL query?

Comment: Oh sorry `SELECT vwreplprev0_.sdan8  AS col_0_0_,
       vwreplprev0_.sdcnid AS col_1_0_,
       vwreplprev0_.sdlitm AS col_2_0_,
       vwreplprev0_.sduorg AS col_3_0_,
       vwreplprev0_.sdaexp AS col_4_0_
FROM   sfe_view.vw_f4211_repl_previa vwreplprev0_
WHERE  vwreplprev0_.sddmct = '9912231583'
GROUP  BY vwreplprev0_.sdan8,
          vwreplprev0_.sdcnid,
          vwreplprev0_.sdlitm,
          vwreplprev0_.sduorg,
          vwreplprev0_.sdaexp
ORDER  BY vwreplprev0_.sdan8 ASC`

Comment: So, the native query has `WHERE vwreplprev0_.sddmct = '9912231583'`, whereas athe criteria query has `WHERE vwreplprev0_.sddmct = ''`. You didn't pass the appropriate parameter value to the query.